# Golang json marshal and encoding give weird output

Tags: json, go, error-handling

I am trying to customise error message for my db query . Following is what I am doing first I create struct Errormessage . Next if there is error in db.query I do this marshaling then encoding and return. But I end up getting this output "e30=" on my postman testing. What could be wrong I check and followed few examples are showing this mechanism ?

```
 error1 := Errormessage{"Error in select"}
        error1_enc,errEn := json.Marshal(error1)
        if errEn != nil {
                
          // if error is not nil
          // print error
          fmt.Println(errEn)
      }
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(error1_enc)
            return
```

/

```
/ declaring a struct
type Errormessage struct{
        
  // defining struct variables
  errormessage string
}
func checkExistUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
 
  r.ParseForm()
  fmt.Println("File Name :", r.FormValue("email"))

  result, err := db.Query("SELECT * from userDetailsss")
  if err != nil {
    //http.Error(w, err, 500)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    w.Header().Set("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff")
    w.WriteHeader(400)
    fmt.Println(err)
    error1 := Errormessage{"Error in select"}
    error1_enc,errEn := json.Marshal(error1)
    if errEn != nil {
            
      // if error is not nil
      // print error
      fmt.Println(errEn)
  }
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(error1_enc)
        return
    //panic(err.Error())
  }
```

// This part is how my db is defined and opened

```
var db *sql.DB
var err error

func main() {
  db, err = sql.Open("mysql", "******#@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/****")
  if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
  }
  defer db.Close()
  router := mux.NewRouter()
  router.HandleFunc("/", DoHealthCheck).Methods("POST")
  router.HandleFunc("/checkExistUser", checkExistUser).Methods("POST")
  log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
  
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243261/discussion-on-question-by-user8012596-golang-json-marshal-and-encoding-give-weir).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1. You are json encoding the already json encoded error. This means that you are json encoding raw json bytes, which is the reason for the weird output.
2. Your `Errormessage` struct's field is unexported. Unexported fields will not be encoded by the encoding/json package.

To fix #1 you can do:

```golang
func checkExistUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.ParseForm()
    fmt.Println("File Name :", r.FormValue("email"))

    result, err := db.Query("SELECT * from userDetailsss")
    if err != nil {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
        w.Header().Set("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff")
        w.WriteHeader(400)
        
        // use only Encode, no need to call json.Marshal
        if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(Errormessage{"Error in select"}); err != nil {
            log.Println("failed to send reposnse:", err)
        }
        return
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

To fix #2 you can do:

```golang
type Errormessage struct {
    // export the field, i.e. change it to start with an upper case letter
    Errormessage string `json:"errormessage"`
}
```